# Java Lambda Function is getting timed out while connecting to Informix DB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-java-sdk

I have a lambda function written in **Java**. I have written database connection logic in lambda function. My database is Informix DB , which is outside AWS. Whenever, lambda runs and try to connect to DB, it gets time-out every-time. Can we connect to database outside AWS via lambda function?

Comment: Where is the database hosted?  It seems likely that there is something blocking the incoming connection.  I'd start there.

Comment: Where is your Lambda hosted? AWS public zone or did you configure as part of your VPC?

Comment: Have you tried this solution? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

Comment: @ChrisWilliams Currently lambda is in VPC, it was getting timeout even in No VPC. Btw, lambda has access to internet in VPC as well

Comment: @stdunbar database in hosted on on-premises server. (not in AWS)

Comment: Can any resource in your VPC access the DB? Worth checking to determine if its Lambda or your network configuration. Try booting up an EC2 and `telnet` to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is Resolved!!

We were using hostname in our DB connection string. We now are using IP address and it is connecting now.

```
connectionString = jdbc:informix-sqli://<IP Address>/xxx:xxx
```

Thanks @madhead, @Chris Williams and all others for sharing their ideas! It really helped.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check that your Lambda actually can access resources outside the AWS, if it uses VPC.
2. If you're sure it can access external resources – increase Lambda timeout, which is 15 seconds by default. BTW, Java-based Lambda functions [experience](https://mikhail.io/serverless/coldstarts/aws) cold starts up to a few seconds. Current maximum execution time (timeout) for a Lambda function is 15 minutes.

Comment: Lambda is in VPC and has access to internet. Also, lambda's timeout is 10 min. While connecting to DB, I am getting connection timeout error in code.

Comment: Does your database server have any network restrictions? Like IP blacklists or whitelists?